# Removing punctuation/numbers from text problem

Tags: python, nltk

I had some code that worked fine removing punctuation/numbers using regular expressions in python, I had to change the code a bit so that a stop list worked, not particularly important. Anyway, now the punctuation isn't being removed and quite frankly i'm stumped as to why.

```
import re
import nltk

# Quran subset
filename = raw_input('Enter name of file to convert to ARFF with extension, eg. name.txt: ')

# create list of lower case words
word_list = re.split('\s+', file(filename).read().lower())
print 'Words in text:', len(word_list)
# punctuation and numbers to be removed
punctuation = re.compile(r'[-.?!,":;()|0-9]')
for word in word_list:
    word = punctuation.sub("", word)
print word_list
```

Any pointers on why it's not working would be great, I'm no expert in python so it's probably something ridiculously stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
for word in word_list:
    word = punctuation.sub("", word)
```

to

```
word_list = [punctuation.sub("", word) for word in word_list]
```

Assignment to `word` in the `for-loop` above, simply changes the value referenced by this temporary variable. It does not alter `word_list`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not updating your word list. Try

```
for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
    word_list[i] = punctuation.sub("", word)
```

Remember that although `word` starts off as a reference to the string object in the `word_list`, assignment rebinds the name `word` to the new string object returned by the `sub` function. It doesn't change the originally referenced object.